# is it a good manner holding project parts separately

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, project

Is it a good manner to split a software project in different sub projects. I want to separate the different, more ore less complex, dialogs to single projects in my solution. Every dialog is build by the mvvm pattern/paradigm. Now I want to initiate the "main" project an hold the different subproject only as reference. Am I running in problems, when using unit tests e.g.?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a separation of:

- UI
- Business / ViewModels
- Data layer

is quite common and a good habbit.

For UI specific. It is usually not necessary, unless you want to expose your UI components as a external library.

This will create some overhead, and sometimes leave you with a headache. (I tried it once with pre-compiled pages in MVC: bad idea).

My personal opinion: if you're not using it as external library in different project, it's not worth the extra work. (versioning, UI-threading stuff, other unforeseen issues...)

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a project into different projects is good. But it depends how you separate it. If you are putting views in one project, view models in other, model in other, then this would be really bad. Keep all UI stuff in one project and model in other.

When following MVVM, I usually have two projects. One is exe containing Views and ViewModels while second project containing Model data. There are two unit-tests projects one for application (unit-testing of viewModels) and one for data. Now here Model can further split into multiple projects depends on what Model contains.

Comment: Actually I want to split every dialog in one project. Each dialog is a closed mvvm project. So I could test echt dialog separately. In the "main" project I can't use real mvvm because its a given framework which do not really support mvvm.

Comment: Do you mean your project will contain only a xaml (view) and a cs (viewModel) file? If yes then it is bad. If you think that your dialog will be used in other applications as well then it might be good (but I haven't seen like this).

Comment: Every single project holds several views, models and viewmodels/controllers.

Comment: Have you implemented this? Can you upload your project structure?